# VMware ESXI Change Block Tracking record

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi

I wanted to know if anyone could answer where the change block tracking record is kept as I have a VMware ESXI and backup virtual machines. I ask because I have backup software doing local incremental backups regularly to the server but I want to have another backup offsite that does one full backup and future incremental but less often will this conflict with the Changed Block Tracking of the local backup. I shall make sure both backups are not running together. If someone could tell me if it is recorded on the virtual machine that is backed up, then I guess it will conflict. But if it is recorded on the backup software then I don’t see that it will conflict.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VMWare official KB about block tracking](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1031873)

You can disable block tracking by editing the parameter called:

```
ctkEnabled
```

to false.
You can do so by manually editing the VMX file (for each disk your VM has) or by CLI commands, as described in the above official guide.

However, disabling block tracking could be potentially unsafe for your data.
Depending on the license you have, ESXi ***already*** provides several backup or redundancy methods.

If you happen to be on a free license, you can use third-party tools like [Veeam Backup & Replication Free](https://www.veeam.com/virtual-machine-backup-solution-free.html).